# backbone is not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm just learning backbone.js. I have written the example below but it does not work, why?

It should just display the name in my div element.

```
(function($) {

    var Item = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot: '/api/camp/1/'
    });

    var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: '#reward_view',

        initialize: function() {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render'); // every function that uses 'this' as the current object should be in here


        },

        render: function() {
            console.log(this)
            $(this.el).html('<h1>Hello' + this.model.get('name') + '</h1>');
            return this; // for chainable calls, like .render().el
        }

    });

    var reward_view = new ListView();

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Where are you calling `render`?

Comment: from the code above, you haven't instantiated your model, and your view does not know that instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the instanciation of your model, then you have to fetch that model and pass it to your view, after that you have to call render of your view.

```
(function($) {

var Item = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/api/camp/1/'
});

var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '#reward_view',

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render'); // every function that uses 'this' as the current object should be in here


    },

    render: function() {
        console.log(this)
        $(this.el).html('<h1>Hello' + this.model.get('name') + '</h1>');
        return this; // for chainable calls, like .render().el
    }

});
var myItem = new Item();
myItem.fetch();
var reward_view = new ListView({model:myItem});
reward_view.render();

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: In your example, it's possible (most likely) that `render` will be called before the model's data is populated from the `fetch` call.